# Get value from a textbox and pass to the next text box as suggestion

Tags: javascript, php, textbox

$partOne = strtok($filename, '.');I have a text box suppose to be url:

```
     <label>URL:</label>
  <input name="url" type="text" id="url" size="20" />
```

And I want to get the last name of that url to display on the second text box when user click there to type:

```
   <label>NAME:</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" />
```

What I tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var url = document.getElementById('url').value; 
    var name = <?php $path = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_PATH); $filename = basename($path);$partOne = strtok($filename, '.'); echo $partOne; ?>;       
    document.getElementById('name').value = name;
}
</script>
```

and make a button to test it:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test Button!</button>
```

But it looks like the java script has something wrong, suspecting it is php in java script part.
How can I archive my purpose (final solution is without clicking on test button; user click to the second box and there is a text there that they can edit).

Comment: try to set the string value with `''` like `var name = '<?php $path = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_PATH); $filename = basename($path); echo $partOne; ?>';`

Comment: That one I tried! It not working !

Comment: what are you passing in name? Why not just `echo $partOne;`, what is the sense here to keep `$path = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_PATH); $filename = basename($path);` even you are not using these variables?

Comment: Sorry, I missed $partOne = strtok($filename, '.'); in the code, just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ajax call at that point. The behavior you expect cannot be done the above way. Once the page is displayed on the browser, there is no more `PHP`, there is just HTML and JS. This is because PHP is a server side language.

You have two options to make the form work as you want, either do your Url processing step with Javascript or make Ajax fetch results from the server, behind the scene.

```
   <label>URL:</label>
   <input name="url" type="text" id="url" size="20" />


   <label>NAME:</label>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" />


<script>
$("#url").change(function()
{
    $.ajax({

            url:"parseurl.php?key="+$("#url").val(),
            }).done(function(data)
            {
                   $("#name").val(data);
            });
});
</script>
```

where `parseurl.php` is

```
<?php
    $path = parse_url($_GET['key'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $filename = basename($path);$partOne = strtok($filename, '.'); 
    echo $partOne; 
?>
```

Comment: I just put the first section to java script, and second to a new file called "parseurl.php" but I put url to the url box, there is nothing happen.

Comment: sorry, the $_GET must be using index 'key' and not 'url'. modified.

Comment: I dont see any difference. Did u tried the code and is it running ?

Comment: i have similar code running on my server.. what do you get when you visit parseurl on browser?

Comment: I got : "Notice: Undefined index: key in C:\xampp\htdocs\parseurl.php on line 2"

Comment: well,i meant parseurl.php?key="yoururl.com/dir/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61977/discussion-between-rjv-and-user1314404).

Comment: Yep, I got: the name that I want to display. But how come it not working with the original file?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I should put the script below the body html. Now it works well ! Great answer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this:

```
  $('input[name=url]').focusout(function(){
      var url = $('input[name=url]').val();
      if(url.indexOf('/') != -1) // If there is a slash in the url.. 'google.at/test.html'
      {
          var urlarray = url.split('/'); // Split the url into an array..
          var urlerg = urlarray[urlarray.length-1]; // Take the last item of the array
          $('#dlist').append('<option value="'+ urlerg+ '">'+urlerg +'</option>');
      }
      else
      {         
          $('#dlist').append('<option value="'+url+'">'+url+'</option>');
      }
  });
```

And this is the input/datalist item:

```
  <label>URL:</label>
  <input name="url" type="text" id="url" size="20" />
  <label>NAME:</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" list="dlist" id="name" size="20" />
  <datalist id="dlist">
  </datalist>
```

So when i write in the URL-Input "www.google.at/test.html" i get in the NAME-Input as suggestion "test.html". And if i only wrote a dokument name without an "/" i get only the dokument name.

[FIDDLE LINK TRY THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rc4sxcte/1/)

Greetings

Comment: Do I need to put document ready or setinterval ? I copied your code but when I click on name box there is nothing appear

Comment: Do you use jQuery? [jQuery.. try it out](http://jquery.com/) If not so 
a) you try it out (simply copy the .js to the root and link it with `<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` or 
b) i change the function to your requirements

Comment: yep, put <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> to the code but still not working. Can u put demo ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I get the second answer work for me. But still kudo for you!